# Is $L^p(X^2) \cong L^p(X) \otimes L^p(X)$ true?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, group-isomorphism

I was wondering if for $X$ a compact set of $\mathbb{R}^d$ with $d \in \mathbb{N}$: $p \in [1,+\infty]$ (especially for the case $p=2$ !) one have
$$L^p(X^2) \cong L^p(X) \otimes L^p(X)$$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: MathJax works in the title field.

Comment: Sure! $X$ is simply a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$, in my case it's just a square of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: Ok, but compact subsets of $\Bbb R^d$ do not necessarily have good measures on them (eg the restriction of the Lebesgue measure to the circle in $\Bbb R^2$ is the zero measure)

Comment: For $p\neq \infty$ its true - provided you understand the tensor product to be the completion of the algebraic tensor product. For $p=\infty$ its false in general. For a proof of $p\neq\infty$ I would start by showing that all polynomials are in the tensor product and that these are dense in $L^p$. For $p=\infty$ construct a counterexample.

Comment: ok thanks i will look up to that!